# Recover bash on amazon

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services

I am using the amazon web service. I accidentally deleted my bash. How do I recover it? HELP!

I try init=/bin/bash and it doesnt work!

I restarted my server as well.

I can only change directory and the path can be seen, but other commands does not work, eg ls does not list the files anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on ubuntu, try issuing this command :

sudo apt-get install --reinstall bash

On RHEL, try

sudo yum reinstall bash